# $\sum_{n=1}^{[a]} a_n f(n) = - \int_1 ^{a}A(x)f'(x)dx + A(a)f(a) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. For $x \geq 0 $, define :

## $A(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{[x]} a_n$

where $[x]$ refers to the greatest integer function

Let $f$ have a continuous derivative in the interval $1 \leq x \leq a$. Use Stieltjes integral to prove that

## $\sum_{n=1}^{[a]} a_n f(n) = - \int_1 ^{a}A(x)f'(x)dx + A(a)f(a) $

**Attempt**:

By integration by parts :

$\int_1 ^{a}A(x)d (f(x) ) + \int_1 ^{a}f(x)d(A(x)) = f(a)A(a) - f(1)A(1) ~~~~~~.......(1)$

Since, $f'$ is continuous, this means, $\int_1 ^{a}A(x)d (f(x) ) = \int_1 ^{a}A(x)f'(x)dx $

And hence, the right side of $(1)$ reduces to :

$\int_1 ^{a}A(x)f'(x)dx + \int_1 ^{a}f(x)d(A(x)) = f(a)A(a) - f(1)A(1)  $

$\implies \int_1 ^{a}A(x)f'(x)dx  = - \int_1 ^{a}f(x)d(A(x)) + f(a)A(a) - f(1)A(1)$

I am now confused how to relate

$\sum_{n=1}^{[a]} a_n f(n)$ and $\int_1 ^{a}A(x)f'(x)dx$

Please tell me how to move ahead.

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(x)$ is a piecewise constant function. Thus 
$$
\int_1^a A(x) f'(x) dx= \sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1} \int_n^{n+1} A(n) f'(x) dx + \int_{[a]}^a A([a]) f'(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1}A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))+A(a)(f(a)-f([a]))
$$
Since $A(n)=A(n-1)+a_n$ we can derive:
$$
\int_1^a A(x) f'(x) dx=\sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1}A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))+A(a)(f(a)-f([a]))=-\sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1}a_n f(n)+A([a]-1) f([a])+A(a)(f(a)-f([a]))=-\sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1}a_n f(n)-a_{[a]} f([a])+A(a)f(a)=\\-\sum_{n=1}^{[a]}a_nf(n)+A(a)(f(a)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. $$
\int_1^a A(x) f'(x) dx= \sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1} \int_n^{n+1} A(n) f'(x) dx + \int_{[a]}^a A([a]) f'(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1}A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))+A(a)(f(a)-f([a]))
$$ . Could you please tell me why this summation in $ \sum_{n=1}^{[a]-1} \int_n^{n+1} A(n) f'(x) dx$  came?

Comment: The integral is sum of integrals on sub intervals. On each subintreval $A(x)$ is constant and only $f'(x)$ is changing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer